# select timestamp older than

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

How can I select items from a database that are older than 12 hours?
I am using a timestamp column to store the time but I don't think I need year, month, or day, only hours.
I have something like this but it doesn't work (no error just returning all data from table)

```
$sql = "SELECT *FROM Y WHERE X and time > now() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR";
```

You're right Salman A .Thanks

Comment: I think you just need to replace `>` with `<`, like `time < NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR`

Answer (score 7):

Try this  :

```
SELECT * FROM Y WHERE X and time < (NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
```

you need `<` rather than `>` as you want to select records older than 12 hours

Comment: It was quite fun to watch yours and @juergen's answer edit race with almost identical modifications.

Comment: @JanTuroň i too assumed the keyword was a problem - but after looking at the list removed my edit ...

Comment: Almost 10 modifications in less than a minute - you are quite a refresher.

Comment: You can also use 12*60*60 instead of `INTERVAL 12 HOUR`. It's just counting seconds.

Comment: Could we use DATE_SUB here? Just was curious.